# getText() gives the text of the child element

Tags: selenium, xpath

I av a `WebElement we` which present the next `HTML` element:

```
<li click="someFunc()">
   <a class="binding"> 
         Screen
    </a>
</li>
```

When I do `we.getText()`, I got the Screen word, even though the text is on the `a` element.

But when I do the next: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(//li[contains(text(),'Screen']))`, it doesn't find the element.

In which command I can use to get the direct text of an element? and I it doesn't possible, so which xpath I should create in order to get the li element, even though the text is not a direct of this WebElement?

Comment: getText() includes all contained text. If you want to avoid recursing downward, you'll have to scan for text nodes that are immediate childen of the `<li>` and accumulate the contents of those.

Comment: @keshlam: So why when I do driver.findElement(By.xpath(//li[contains(text(),'Screen'])), It doesn't find it?

Comment: Your first query is simply running //text(), and not looking at anything related to the <li> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the direct text child notes you can use the XPath

```xml
//li/text()
```

If you want to get the whole text content of all childs, use

```xml
//li/string()
```

To search for all `li` elements which do have `Screen` as text node you can also simply do

```xml
//li[contains(., 'Screen')]
```

as the element will be automatically converted to its atomic value.